# Restrict access to a ssh user to execute only one script

Tags: centos, ssh, scripting

I'm new to linux admin so my question can seem dumb and i'm french so my english isn't good.

I want to create an user account on my centos 7 server. That user will only have access to only one folder by ssh. Inside that folder (example: /home/user1/), there will be 2 scripts: **createftp.sh** & **deleteftp.sh**. I want the user to be able to execute ONLY these scripts and won't be able to do anything else on the server.

Please how can i achieve that ? After some search, i found Chroot to jail user folder & internal-sftp but it only restricts user access to a specific folder and don't allow script executions.

[EDIT]

SOLVED: https://ctrlnotes.com/restrict-a-user-to-ssh-forced-command/#

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/402615/10622916 or https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/ or https://github.com/raforg/sshdo/

Comment: Hi @Bodo ! Thanks for taking time to reply to my post. I really appreciate your help. 

My problem has been solved with this solution: https://ctrlnotes.com/restrict-a-user-to-ssh-forced-command/#